# Почему изменения переменной в цикле остаются в цикле?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Есть функция:

```
function randomName (template) { // template = "adj.en-noun.en"
    var name = ""; //локальная переменная определена
    let words = template.split(' ');
    words.forEach(function(word, i, words) {
        let wordLists = word.split('-');
        wordLists.forEach(function(wordList, n, wordLists) {
            let wordListNameLang = wordList.split('.');
            let wordListPath = './raws/'+wordListNameLang[0]+'list.'+wordListNameLang[1]+'.txt';
            fs.readFile(wordListPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                let fileStrings = data.split('\n');
                let maxString = fileStrings.length - 1;
                let stringNum = getRandomArbitrary(0, maxString);
                name += fileStrings[stringNum]; //Обновление переменной
                console.log(name); // Вывод 3, первое прохождение цикла: praise
                                  // Вывод 4, второе прохождение цикла: praisetepid
            });
        });
        name += " ";
        console.log(name); // Вывод 1 или 2:
    });
    console.log(name); // Вывод 1 или 2:
    return name.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Проблема в переменной `name`. Она объявлена в начале функции с ключевым словом `var`, её областью видимости должна быть вся функция. В цикле данная переменная изменяется без ключевого слова, то есть переопределения нет. Цикл работает корректно, однако проверка значения переменной после выхода их цикла показывает, что она пустая.

У меня две версии, что могло случиться:

- Переменная была определена в цикле, как локальная переменная этого цикла, а глобальная переменная не изменялась;
- Функция продолжила выполнение асинхронно, не дожидаясь окончания работы цикла, на что указывает то, что вывод проверок переменной вне цикла предшествует в консоли выводу из цикла, хотя вывод из цикла показан в порядке его исполнения.

Но я не понимаю, почему это происходит и что с этим делать.

Comment: можно использовать синхронную версию функции: [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) либо возвращающую `Promise`: [fsPromises.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) и работать с Promise, как указано в дубликате

Comment: происходит асинхронное чтение из файла, и вы выходите из цикла прежде чем начнется обновления переменной

Comment: @GenaMoroz да, я уже заменил функцию на синхронную, по совету Grundy, всё заработало.